# Three line equations with cyclically permuted coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

Consider the three linear equations

$ax+by+c=0$
$bx+cy+a=0$
$cx+ay+b=0$

where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$

Prove that
$(A)$If $a+b+c=0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2\neq ab+bc+ac$,then prove that the lines are concurrent.

$(B)$If $a+b+c=0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2= ab+bc+ac$,then entire $xy$ plane.

$(C)$If $a+b+c\neq0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2\neq ab+bc+ac$,then prove that the lines are neither coincident nor concurrent.

$(D)$If $a+b+c\neq 0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2= ab+bc+ac$,then prove that the lines are coincident.

I understood that if the lines are passes through $(1,1)$,then $a+b+c=0$ otherwise not,but i am not clear what does $a^2+b^2+c^2=ab+bc+ca$ mean?

Please help me.

Comment: what did you mean by 'entire $xy$ plane'?And what have you tried?

Comment: Can you do *any* of the problem? Can you see why $a+b+c$ is important? Can you see what $a^2+b^2+c^2=ab+bc+ac$ has to do with it, or where it comes from?

Comment: You may find part of https://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120403102804AAb12bY helpful.

Comment: Have you had a look at that link?

Comment: Question abandoned?

Comment: Well, you were given a suggestion, you gave no indication that you had looked at that suggestion, even when you were asked about it – if you want to "clear your concepts," a good way to start is to engage with the people who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a+b+c=0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=ab+bc+ac$, then it follows that $0=(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ac)$, or $a^2+b^2+c^2=-2(ab+bc+ac)$. Put this together and we will see that in fact $a^2+b^2+c^2=0$, which is only possible if a, b, and с are all 0. This would make all three equations identical and trivially correct on the entire xy plane, just like the option (B) suggested.

**Upd.** Sure enough, the rest is as simple as this. See,
$(a-b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab\ge0\Rightarrow a^2+b^2\ge2ab$ (equals only if $a=b$).
Likewise,
$$b^2+c^2\ge2bc\\
a^2+c^2\ge2ac$$
Sum all that together, and we'll get
$$2a^2+2b^2+2c^2\ge2ab+2bc+2ac$$
So the identity $a^2+b^2+c^2=ab+bc+ac$ is possible only when $a=b=c$, in which case our lines are all the same (or *coincident*, if you want to say it the fancy way).

Is this the only case when they coincide? Well, for the two lines to coincide, their equations must be proportional to each other, as in
$$ax+by+c=0\\
kax+kby+kc=0$$
Plugging our second line into it, we see that $b=ka,\;c=kb,\;a=kc$, hence $k^3=1$. If we are not going to delve into complex numbers (and trust me, we are not), then the only solution is $k=1$, which means $a=b=c$.